# Loop through json and paste in html not working properly

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a fetch api as such:

```
let url ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/20'
const html = document.getElementById('root');


fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => writeToHTML(json))  //vi bruger JSON.stringify(json for at konvertere til en streng)
.catch(error =>console.log("The error is: ", error));



const writeToHTML = (json) =>{
    let html = "";
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
    for(jsonObj in json){
    let jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    html += `<p><b> ${jsonString} </b> </p>`
    }
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = html
}
```

but the output is not working properly, it is only placing the keys, of the json object, where i want each value pair, being displayed on a new line each time.

here is the full json object, I'm fetching, i would prefer to do it with more objects.

```
{"userId":2,"id":20,"title":"doloribus ad provident suscipit at","body":"qui consequuntur ducimus possimus quisquam amet similique\nsuscipit porro ipsam amet\neos veritatis officiis exercitationem vel fugit aut necessitatibus totam\nomnis rerum consequatur expedita quidem cumque explicabo"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are calling `jsonobj` in `for(jsonObj in json)` is not an object it is each property name in the object you call `json`

Try

```
for(let key in json){     
    html += `<p><b>${key} :  ${json[key]} </b> </p>`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop over an object i.e `for(let jsonObj in json){` `jsonObj` is the key not the full object.

So I think your looking for something like:

```
for(let jsonObj in json){
  let jsonString = JSON.stringify(json[jsonObj]);
  html += `<p><b> ${jsonString} </b> </p>`
}
```